# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object - maybe string?

Tags: php, json

I would like to get the value of "Records"

When is try this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('URL');
var_dump($json);
```

This is the result:

```
string(25289) "ï»¿{ "ProductsSummary": { "Records": 10, "TotalRecords": 2874, "TotalPages": 288, "CurrentPage": 1 }, "Products": [ { "...
```

When I try this code

```
$json = file_get_contents('URL');
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj;
echo $obj->{'ProductsSummary'}->{'Records'};
echo $obj->ProductsSummary->Records;
echo $obj[0]->ProductsSummary->Records;
echo $obj->ProductsSummary[0]->Records;
echo $obj->ProductsSummary[1];
```

The Output is:

```
{ "ProductsSummary": { "Records": 10, "TotalRecords": 2879, "TotalPages": 288, "CurrentPage": 1 }, "Products": [ { "Last.... }

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in  ...
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in  ...
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in  ...
```

Comment: What does the question title have to do with the question body? What are you asking exactly? In HTML, carriage returns are ignored by default. That fact has nothing to do with JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: You need to show us the code that gives you the error message for us to know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome at SO! It's those "ï»¿" That's an UTF-8 BOM, most times not welcome, but added by such editors as plain Windows notepad. Check your files with a better editor like notepad++ and convert those files to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I think this can be true. But I am sending my request to an external API. Thus I have deal with what I get :)

Comment: i had to get rid of the BOM. You were right. i used this:

if(substr($json,0,3) == pack("CCC", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF)) $json = substr($json, 3);

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32184933/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not have valid JSON, I'm pretty sure that `json_decode()` is just failing. [As per the manual](http://php.net/json_decode):

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
> true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
> respectively. **`NULL` is returned if the json cannot be decoded** or if the
> encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

You can verify that with e.g. the [is_null()](http://php.net/is_null) function:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
if( is_null($obj) ){
    // Invalid JSON, don't need to keep on working on it
}else{
    // Read data
}
```

... although the proper way would be to explicitly check for errors with [json_last_error()](https://php.net/json_last_error), which should equal `JSON_ERROR_NONE` unless something went wrong.

If everything works fine, `$obj` will be an **object**, thus feeding `echo` with it will never yield anything useful:

```
echo $obj;
```

You might want to use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) instead.

Answer (score 0):

$json is a string. You should decode it first using json_decode($json)

Comment: I'm not sure that you do have an object - can you post the result of get_class($obj)?

Comment: problem solved. it wasnt a valid JSON object. i had a BOM at the beginning