# Remove BOM (ï»¿) from imported .csv file

Tags: php, csv, import, fgetcsv

I want to delete the BOM from my imported file, but it just doesn't seem to work.

I tried to `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $file);` and a str_replace.

I hope anybody sees what I'm doing wrong.

```
$filepath = get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/testing.csv";
            setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
            ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
            $file = fopen($filepath, "r") or die("Error opening file");
            $i = 0;
            while(($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $c = 0;
                    foreach($line as $col) {
                        $cols[$c] = utf8_encode($col);
                        $c++;
                    }
                } else if($i > 0) {
                    $c = 0;
                    foreach($line as $col) {
                        $data[$i][$cols[$c]] = utf8_encode($col);
                        $c++;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
```

-----------
SOLVED VERSION:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

$path = get_home_path();        
$filepath = $path .'wp-content/themes/pon/testing.csv';
$content = file_get_contents($filepath); 
file_put_contents($filepath, str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'', $content));

// FILE_PUT_CONTENTS AUTOMATICCALY CLOSES THE FILE
$file = fopen($filepath, "r") or die("Error opening file"); 

$i = 0;
while(($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if($i == 0) {
        $c = 0;
        foreach($line as $col) {
            $cols[$c] = $col;
            $c++;
        }
    } else if($i > 0) {
        $c = 0;
        foreach($line as $col) {
            $data[$i][$cols[$c]] = $col;
            $c++;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I found that it removes the BOM and adjusts the file by overwriting it with the new data. The problem is that the rest of my script doesn't work anymore and I can't see why. It is a new .csv file

Comment: `$cols[$c]` inside your first foreach is pointless. `$cols` is a COPY of whatever line/field you're processing. you need `foreach($lines as $key => $col) { $lines[$key] = utf8_encode($col); }`

Comment: PHP docs comment for fgetcsv has a nice answer, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#122696 - open the file, read and move filepointer and check if first 3 bytes are equal to the BOM string, if not, rewind and then proceed with fgetcv

Comment: [the Same issue has been solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc) fixedstring = decodeURIComponent(escape(utfstring));

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeBomUtf8($s){
  if(substr($s,0,3)==chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF'))){
       return substr($s,3);
   }else{
       return $s;
   }
}
```

Comment: It gives me this: `Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

Comment: What are you passing into this function? It should be like that:

`$file = 'something.csv';`

`$content = file_get_contents($file);`

`var_dump(removeBomUtf8($content));`
And then start processing this file.

Comment: in this line:
`$content = file_get_contents($file);` change `$file` to `$filepath`

Comment: Okay this is some progress. Thnx. I now get a string with al my csv data without the BOM. Awesome. If I remove the `var_dump` and let my script continue with `while(($line = fgetcsv(removeBomUtf8($content), 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {` It gives me a blank page with no error or progress. Any ideas?

Comment: I slightly changed your idea ( don't know if it is the best but it works.) I found that `file_put_contents` closes the file so I just had to reopen it. Thanks for your help

Comment: To remove UTF16 Little Endian BOM `(substr($s, 0, 2) == chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE))`

Comment: This is correct answer, You have to send single parameter in string only that contains BOM. and it'll work

Answer (score 7):

Correct way is to skip BOM if present in file (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#122696):

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$file = fopen($filepath, "r") or die("Error opening file");
if (fgets($file, 4) !== "\xef\xbb\xbf") //Skip BOM if present
        rewind($file); //Or rewind pointer to start of file

$i = 0;
while(($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: that is right but it do not remove bom and this is the question

Comment: `auto_detect_line_endings` is deprecated in PHP 8.1 and will be removed in PHP 9.0. https://php.watch/versions/8.1/auto_detect_line_endings-ini-deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Isn't the BOM there to give you a clue on how to reencode the input to something your script/app/database needs? Just deleting isn't gonna help.

This is how I force a string (drawn from a file with `file_get_contents()`) to be encoded in UTF-8 and get rid of the BOM as well:

```
switch (true) { 
    case (substr($string,0,3) == "\xef\xbb\xbf") :
        $string = substr($string, 3);
        break;
    case (substr($string,0,2) == "\xfe\xff") :                            
        $string = mb_convert_encoding(substr($string, 2), "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE");
        break;
    case (substr($string,0,2) == "\xff\xfe") :                            
        $string = mb_convert_encoding(substr($string, 2), "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
        break;
    case (substr($string,0,4) == "\x00\x00\xfe\xff") :
        $string = mb_convert_encoding(substr($string, 4), "UTF-8", "UTF-32BE");
        break;
    case (substr($string,0,4) == "\xff\xfe\x00\x00") :
        $string = mb_convert_encoding(substr($string, 4), "UTF-8", "UTF-32LE");
        break;
    default:
        $string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $string);
};
```

Comment: I like this, except that UTF-32LE will never be detected because UTF-16LE will trigger it first. Longest comparisons should be at the top.

Answer (score 5):

If the character encoding functions don't work for you (as is the case for me in some situations) and you know for a fact that your file always has a BOM, you can simply use an fseek() to skip the first 3 bytes, which is the length of the BOM.

```
$fp = fopen("testing.csv", "r");
fseek($fp, 3);
```

You should also not use explode() to split your CSV lines and columns because if your column contains the character by which you split, you will get an incorrect result. Use this instead:

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $arrayLine = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ";", '"');
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you can not be sure if there is a BOM Marker, better check for it and rewind if not:

  `if (!fread($handle, 3)==chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF)) {    rewind($handle);     }`  instead of the `fseek`

Answer (score 1):

Read data with `file_get_contents` then use `mb_convert_encoding` to convert to UTF-8

### UPDATE

```
$filepath = get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/testing.csv";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filepath);
$fileContent = mb_convert_encoding($fileContent, "UTF-8");
$lines = explode("\n", $fileContent);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $conls = explode(";", $line);
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: @Interactive `file_get_contents` reads whole file. `explode` it by "\n" or "\r\n". It gives back an array. Then walk through on this array.

Comment: If I run this it gives me an Array where the 'titlefields' are in the first array and every following Array contains information per person. This is great but I have no idea how to use this for what I'm doing. So I guess I'll be pulling a all nighter.

Comment: I slightly changed your idea ( don't know if it is the best but it works.) I found that `file_put_contents` closes the file so I just had to reopen it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution, this solved my case: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#116763

```
$bom = pack('CCC', 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF);
if (strncmp($yourString, $bom, 3) === 0) {
    $body = substr($yourString, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [@Tomas'z answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32185872/1563422) as the main inspiration for this, and [@Nolwennig's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-imported-csv-file#comment88886421_32185872):

```
// Strip byte order marks from a string
function strip_bom($string, $type = 'utf8') {
    $length = 0;

    switch($type) {
        case 'utf8':
            $length = substr($string, 0, 3) === chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ? 3 : 0;
        break;

        case 'utf16_little_endian':
            $length = substr($string, 0, 2) === chr(0xFF) . chr(0xFE) ? 2 : 0;
        break;
    }

    return $length ? substr($string, $length) : $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone's answers here, and I think they are all great *work-arounds* for what is clearly a problem with the PHP code itself.  Its been listed in PHP Bug Tracker since 2003-02-07 08:46.  Its current status is **WONT FIX** in [PHP Bug Tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22108), but I have just recently posted a comment suggesting that this issue be resolved.

There's an option *to vote on this as a problem*, and maybe that might get this bug some attention and maybe get it solved.

According to [**RFC3629**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629#page-6): adding BOM to a file is...

> ...to prepend a U+FEFF character to a stream of UCS characters as a 'signature'.  A receiver of such a serialized stream may then use the initial character as a hint that the stream consists of UCS characters and also to recognize which UCS encoding is involved...

It's clear that the purpose of the BOM is not to be interpreted as a character in the data, but, as clearly stated, it's a "signature" of UTF-8 characters and a "hint" about the encoding of the characters.

Good code should adhere to the RFCs, not dance around the problem with unnecessary steps.