# PHP cannot parse CSV correctly (file is in UTF-16LE)

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding, byte-order-mark, utf-16le

I am trying to parse a CSV file using PHP.
The file uses **commas as delimiter** and **double quotes for fields containing comma(s)**, as:

```
foo,"bar, baz",foo2
```

**The issue** I am facing is that I get fields containing comma(s) separated. I get:

- `"2`
- `rue du ..."`

Instead of: `2, rue du ...`.

---

**Encoding:**
The file doesn't seem to be in UTF8. It has weird wharacters at the beginning ([apparently not BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-imported-csv-file), looks like this when converted from ASCII to UTF8: `ÿþ`) and doesn't displays accents.

- My code editor (Atom) tells the encoding is **UTF-16 LE**
- using [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on the csv lines it returns **ASCII**

But it fails to convert:

- [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) converts from `ASCII` but returns asian characters from `UTF-16LE`
- [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) returns **Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-16LE`/`ASCII` to `UTF8` is not allowed**.

---

**Parsing:**
I tried to parse with this one-liner (see [those 2 comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764)) using `str_getcsv()`:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file['tmp_name']));
```

I then tried with `fgetcsv()` :

```
$f = fopen($file['tmp_name'], 'r');
while (($l = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    $arr[] = $l;
}
$f = fclose($f);
```

In both ways I get my adress field in 2 parts. But when I try this code sample I get correctly parsed fields:

```
$str = 'foo,"bar, baz",foo2,azerty,"ban, bal",doe';
$data = str_getcsv($str);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

---

To sum up with questions:

- What are the characters at the beginning of the file ?
- How could I be sure about the encoding ? *(Atom reads the file with `UTF-16 LE` and doesn't display weird characters at the beginning)*
- What makes the csv parsing functions fail ?
- If I should rely on something else to parse the lines of the CSV, what could I use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I finally solved it myself:*

I sent the file into online encoding detection websites which returned **UTF16LE**. After checking about what is **UTF16LE** it says it has **BOM (Byte Order Mark)**.
My previous attempts were using `file()` which returns an ***array of the lines*** of a file and with `fopen()` which returns a resource, but we still parse ***line by line***.

The working solution came in my mind about **converting the whole file (every line at once)** instead of converting each line separately. Here is a working solution:

```
$f = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);          // Get the whole file as string
$f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');   // Convert the file to UTF8
$f = preg_split("/\R/", $f);                        // Split it by line breaks
$f = array_map('str_getcsv', $f);                   // Parse lines as CSV data
```

I don't get the adress fields separated at internal commas anymore.

Comment: I ended up with array_walk so i could specify str_getcsv with unique delimiter, THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, this is working better for me than the other solutions I found.

I came up with a little improvement, which removes the first two characters in the file (the BOM markers) and then reads and csv-parse the file line-by-line, for when there is the need of working on each record.

Removing the first two characters in the file proved necessary to me, otherwise the str_getcsv function didn't work well on the first field of the first line.

```php
    $f = substr(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']), 2);
    $f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');
    $f = preg_split("/\R/", $f);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($f); $i++) {
      $record = str_getcsv($f[$i], "\t", '"');
      //...work with the record...
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).