# Problem with double quotes in first key using array_map

Tags: php

Using the code below, I can create an associative array from a CSV file. 
It works fine, only problem is, the first key for each row is saved with double quotes (") and I don't understand why.

```
/* Map Rows and Loop Through Them */
$rows   = array_map(function($row) { return str_getcsv($row, ';', '"'); }, file('test.csv'));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv    = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);   
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($csv);
echo "</pre>";
```

When I print, I get this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ["TEST"] => 
            [EMAIL] => mail@test.com
            [NAVN] => Donald Duck
            [ADDRESSE] => Paradisæblevej 111
            [POSTNRBY] => 1234  Andeby
            [TELEFON] => 12345678
            [TUR] => 49
            [TURNAVN] => Title
            [ANTAL] => 1
            [BELOEBIALT] => 695
            [BONKODE] => 99900714
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ["TEST"] => 
            [EMAIL] => mail@test.com
            [NAVN] => Donald Duck
            [ADDRESSE] => Paradisæblevej 111
            [POSTNRBY] => 1234  Andeby
            [TELEFON] => 12345678
            [TUR] => 49
            [TURNAVN] => Title
            [ANTAL] => 1
            [BELOEBIALT] => 695
            [BONKODE] => 99900714
        )

)
```

My header looks like this:

```
"TEST";"EMAIL";"NAVN";"ADDRESSE";"POSTNRBY";"TELEFON";"TUR";"TURNAVN";"ANTAL";"BELOEBIALT";"BONKODE"
```

CSV file looks like this:

```
"TEST";"EMAIL";"NAVN";"ADDRESSE";"POSTNRBY";"TELEFON";"TUR";"TURNAVN";"ANTAL";"BELOEBIALT";"BONKODE"
"";"mail@test.com";"Donald Duck";"Paradisæblevej 111";"1234  Andeby";"12345678";"49";"Title";"1";"695";"99900714"
"";"mail@test.com";"Donald Duck";"Paradisæblevej 111";"1234  Andeby";"12345678";"49";"Title";"1";"695";"99900714"
```

Note the quotes in "Test"... 
How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Any funky invisible characters in the `"TEST"` header…? Check with a hex editor.

Comment: can you give some data from csv? (maybe quotes inside the header itself)

Comment: If I remove the TEST header, then double quotes appear in EMAIL instead. There are no invisible characters in the file besides line return at the end of each line.

Comment: Here's a likely guess: Your file starts with a Unicode BOM (byte order mark), which is invisible but convinces `str_getcsv` that this cell is _not_ surrounded by quotes.

Comment: *"There are no invisible characters in the file"* – You have confirmed this how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove BOM (ï»¿) from imported .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%c3%af-from-imported-csv-file)

Comment: You couldn't have known, but we now know that your question is a duplicate. There's code there for how to check for and skip the BOM, see if you can apply it to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guess: Your file starts with a Unicode BOM (byte order mark), which is invisible but convinces `str_getcsv` that this cell is *not* surrounded by quotes.

To test it: Open your csv file in an editor and save it as Latin-1, or any other 8-bit encoding. The problem should disappear (but you might mangle the content).

To fix it: Ideally, you would specify the correct encoding (utf-8?) when you open the file. PHP doesn't seem to define a UTF-8+BOM encoding, though. So you can try to apply the (ugly) solution from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-imported-csv-file) question, which is about the same problem. (Or you can switch to Python, which does have a `utf-8-bom` encoding :-P )

Comment: I actually just tried to create a new csv file directly on the server and copy the content over. Then the issue disappeared. So this could mean file encoding issue, or the Unicode BOM you mentioned.

Comment: This is a BOM issue. If I do a json_encode  on my $header I see this output ["\ufeff\"EMAIL\"","NAVN","ADDRESSE","POSTNRBY","TELEFON","TUR","TURNAVN","ANTAL","BEL\u00d8BIALT","BONKODE"]

Comment: Thought so, I've been bitten by this kind of thing before. And the BOM is not even supposed to be there in UTF-8 files, Microsoft just likes to add it everywhere.