# PHP: One key is not bring back it's value

Tags: php

I have an array as follows using var_dump

```
array(26) {
  ["SUPPLIER_NAME"]=>
  string(14) ""Company Ltd""
  ["INACTIVATE"]=>
  string(13) ""Keep Active""
  ["SUPPLIER_INACTIVE_DATE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SITE_INACTIVE_DATE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ADDRESS2"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ADDRESS3"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

However when I try and do the following, it's blank, no value returns

```
echo $array["SUPPLIER_NAME"]
```

When I do any other key, it works, just not on **SUPPLIER_NAME**

Any ideas?

**EDITED**

We consume an array as follows (I'm just referencing the first key in this array):

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```

This produces:

```
array(26) {
  ["SUPPLIER_NAME"]=>
  string(14) ""Company Ltd""
  ["SUPPLIER_TYPE"]=>
  string(13) ""Keep Active""
...
...
  ["ADDRESS2"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ADDRESS3"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I then try and do the following which spits out nothing:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result[0]["SUPPLIER_NAME"]);
echo '</pre>';
```

However, this produces the correct data (and every other key works as well):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result[0]["SUPPLIER_TYPE"]);
echo '</pre>';
```

I did the following:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(array_keys($result[0]));
echo '</pre>';
```

I got:

```
array(26) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "SUPPLIER_NAME"
```

Comment: can we see full code block relating to this.. at the moment this can't be reproduced, we can only guess. Also, CAPITALS IN PROGRAMMING IS NOT FUN TO READ! Use lowercase - much nicer on the eyes

Comment: You probably have some invisible characters *somewhere*. Either in your code trying to access `$array["SUPPLIER_NAME"]`, or in the actual array. Try `var_dump(array_keys($array))` for starters…

Comment: Copy&pasting your debug output out from above into a hex editor shows that you have a Byte Order Mark (hex `ef bb bf`) preceding the `SUPPLIER_NAME`.

Comment: @deceze there is one.

Comment: If this is from a CSV file, then check for BOM (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-imported-csv-file)

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks all, how would I amend the key name to remove these given I don't control the data I receive?

Comment: Where does the data come from at all? Use `echo urlencode(array_keys($result[0])[0])` to see what weird bytes you're dealing with exactly…

Answer (score 1):

There is an hidden character in your array :

```
array(26) {
//  v---------------------- there
  ["SUPPLIER_NAME"]=>
  string(14) ""Company Ltd""
  ["INACTIVATE"]=>
  string(13) ""Keep Active""
  ["SUPPLIER_INACTIVE_DATE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SITE_INACTIVE_DATE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ADDRESS2"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ADDRESS3"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

"SUPPLIER_NAME" != "SUPPLIER_NAME"
```