# First item from csv file returns unreadable characters

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv reader *(code at the bottom)* and the **first item** of the **first row** returns unreadable characters while the second row or second item from the first row is just fine.
If found out I can view these charaters when I array_map the variable with utf8_encode.

```
var_dump($data[0][0])
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data[0][0]); $i++){
    var_dump($data[0][0][$i]);
}
var_dump(array_map("utf8_encode", $data[0])[0]);
```

returns

```
string(11) "﻿voornaam"
string(1) "�" string(1) "�" string(1) "�" string(1) "v" string(1) "o" string(1) "o" string(1) "r" string(1) "n" string(1) "a" string(1) "a" string(1) "m"
string(14) "ï»¿voornaam"
```

How can I remove these charaters when I don't even know what to look for?

**CSV Reader**

Variables:

```
$this->fp = fopen($file_name, "r");
$this->parse_header = false;
$this->delimiter = ",";
$this->length = 1000;
```

Actual code:

```
function get($max_lines = 0)
{
    //if $max_lines is set to 0, then get all the data

    $data = array();

    if ($max_lines > 0)
        $line_count = 0;
    else
        $line_count = -1; // so loop limit is ignored

    while ($line_count < $max_lines && ($row = fgetcsv($this->fp, $this->length, $this->delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($this->parse_header) {
            foreach ($this->header as $i => $heading_i) {
                $row_new[$heading_i] = $row[$i];
            }
            $data[] = $row_new;
        } else {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        if ($max_lines > 0)
            $line_count++;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The function is being called with no `max_lines`

Comment: Your CSV file has a UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: All I did was "save as csv", is it possible to remove the BOM or convert it to regular UTF-8?

Comment: Depends on what program you "saved as csv" from… see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750807/476.

Comment: Found the answer to what I was searching as a comment in the above link.

I do think this question is still important for people who might not know about UTF-8 DOM like I did