# fgetcsv() returns strings that have wrong length and don't match with regex (invisible characters I can't find?)

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

So this one let me doubt my sanity - I'm currently working on a simple script that should read URLs from a csv file and than perform a regex but my pattern kept on failing. Upon close inspection I noticed something strange: The strings that fgetcsv returns showing a completely wrong length when displayed with var_dump(). Any idea what is going on here and how to sanitize this string?

Sample-Code:

```
<?php
$read = fopen("input.csv","r");
while($data = fgetcsv($read,null,",","\"","\\")){
    var_dump($data[0]);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($data[0]);
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

And the response looks like this:

```
string(25) "﻿/index.html"
ASCII
string(23) "/login.html"
ASCII
string(15) "/insta/"
ASCII
```

The strings are the same that are in my csv-file, but as you see the string length reported isn't right. What is going on here? Are there invisible characters I'm not seeing? Is it some strange encoding problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: Split the string, iterate over each character and use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php. This will show you what you have. Alternatively you could try `trim`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove BOM (ï»¿) from imported .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%c3%af-from-imported-csv-file). In fact, the string `"/index.html"` is `\u0022\uFEFF\u002F\u0069\u006E\u0064\u0065\u0078\u002E\u0068\u0074\u006D\u006C\u0022` (incl. double quotes; starts with - `"` (U+0022,  *Quotation Mark*)
- `` (U+FEFF,  *Zero Width No-Break Space*)
- `/` (U+002F,  *Solidus*)).

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you I tried that. For "/index.html" I got the following output:

`239
187
191
47
0
105
0
110
0
100
0
101
0
120
0
46
0
104
0
116
0
109
0
108
0`

I guess the zeros are a/the problem? But what are they? Where do the come from and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: I think that may be UTF-16 encoding. Google "convert from utf-16 to utf-8"

Comment: Thank you - i've tried it and thrown everything I found at it mb_convert_encoding(), iconv(),... but didn't have any luck yet