# Undefined array key just for first key in array, every other key works fine. Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

So i am trying to import data from csv file to the database. Everything except first key in array works fine. All the rest data is inserted in db.

```
    $boltReport    = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if(!empty($row)){
            $boltReport[] = array_combine($header_row, $row);
        }
    }
    $boltReportTrimed = array();
    foreach($boltReport as $driver){
        if (!empty($driver['Telefonski_broj_vozaca'])){
            if($driver['Period'] != 'Period'){
                if(!empty($driver['Utilization'])){
                    $driver['report_for_week']= $week;
                    $boltReportTrimed[] = $driver;
                    $count++;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    $driverData = new BoltReportModel();
    $findRecord = $driverData->where('report_for_week', $week)->countAllResults();

    $count1 = 0;
    foreach($boltReportTrimed as $driver){
            if($findRecord == 0){
                                
                if($driverData->insert($driver)){
                    $count1++;}
                }
            }
```

Here i am doing some filtering and using model to insert data in database. All the data except first item in array $boltReportTrimed is inserted in database.

So to debug i was using print_r and echo to check what data i have.

Here is the code

```
foreach($boltReportTrimed as $driver){
    if($findRecord == 0){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($driver);
        echo '</pre>';
        die();

        if($driverData->insert($driver)){
            $count1++;}
        }
```

With this code i get response like this:

```
Array
(
    [Vozac] => Ante Antunović
    [Telefonski_broj_vozaca] => +385958759630
    [Period] => Tjedan 2023-01-09 - 2023-01-15
    [Bruto_iznos] => 0.00
    [Otkazna_naknada] => 0.00
    [Naknada_za_rezervaciju_(placanje)] => 0.00
    [Naknada_za_rezervaciju_(odbitak)] => 0.00
    [Naknada_za_cestarinu] => 0.00
    [Bolt_naknada] => 0.00
    [Voznje_placene_gotovinom_(prikupljena_gotovina)] => 0.00
    [Popusti_na_voznje_na_gotovinu_od_Bolt_] => 0.00
    [Bonus] => 0.00
    [Nadoknade] => 
    [Povrati_novca] => 0.00
    [Napojnica] => 0.00
    [Tjedno_stanje_racuna] => 0.00
    [Sati_na_mrezi] => 0.20
    [Utilization] => 0.00
    [report_for_week] => 02
)
```

I know it's almost all 0 but data is correct. First array item does not get inserted in database so i was trying to echo first item with this code:

```
foreach($boltReportTrimed as $driver){
    if($findRecord == 0){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($driver);
        echo $driver['Vozac'];
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
        
        if($driverData->insert($driver)){
            $count1++;}
        }
```

Here is one more thing i was trying:

```
                foreach($boltReportTrimed as $driver){
                        if($findRecord == 0){
                                            echo '<pre>';
                                            print_r($driver);
                                            //echo $driver['Vozac'];
                                            echo '</pre>';
                            $firstKey = array_key_first($driver);

                            var_dump($firstKey);                
                            
                            die();
```

And result is:

```
Array
(
    [Vozac] => Ante Antunović
    [Telefonski_broj_vozaca] => +385958733630
    [Period] => Tjedan 2023-01-09 - 2023-01-15
    [Bruto_iznos] => 0.00
    [Otkazna_naknada] => 0.00
    [Naknada_za_rezervaciju_(placanje)] => 0.00
    [Naknada_za_rezervaciju_(odbitak)] => 0.00
    [Naknada_za_cestarinu] => 0.00
    [Bolt_naknada] => 0.00
    [Voznje_placene_gotovinom_(prikupljena_gotovina)] => 0.00
    [Popusti_na_voznje_na_gotovinu_od_Bolt_] => 0.00
    [Bonus] => 0.00
    [Nadoknade] => 
    [Povrati_novca] => 0.00
    [Napojnica] => 0.00
    [Tjedno_stanje_racuna] => 0.00
    [Sati_na_mrezi] => 0.20
    [Utilization] => 0.00
    [report_for_week] => 02
)
string(8) "Vozac"
```

Now i got this error from the title:

> ErrorException
> Undefined array key "Vozac"

echoing any other key works fine and i get expected results
Help me please.

By @nnichols suggestion i try this:

```
print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split('Vozac'))));
print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split($firstKey))));
```

And result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 56
    [1] => 6f
    [2] => 7a
    [3] => 61
    [4] => 63
)
Array
(
    [0] => feff
    [1] => 56
    [2] => 6f
    [3] => 7a
    [4] => 61
    [5] => 63
)
```

Any further help or suggestions are welcome because i have no idea what this means. Thank you in advance

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If that array you show is called `$boltReportTrimed` then `echo $driver['Vozac'];` does not exist, the first occurance of the array is in `$driver` so $driver is `Ante Antunović` the content of the first occurance in that array

Comment: The `print_r($driver);` should have shown you `Ante Antunović` the first time rounf the loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly Wrong, $driver is an array to, you can see what did i get with print_r, first array key is 'Vozac' and value is 'Ante Antunović'

Comment: In that case cound there be a hidden corruption in the code or maybe the data for that key

Comment: It looks like a charset issue. `string(8) "Vozac"` when `string(5) "Vozac"` expected?

Comment: @nnichols hmm interesting. it could be. Any idea how to fix this? Or atleast to check if that's the issue.

Comment: Try comparing output of `print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split('Vozac'))));` and `print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split($firstKey))));`

Comment: @nnichols
`code` Array
(
    [0] => 56
    [1] => 6f
    [2] => 7a
    [3] => 61
    [4] => 63
)
Array
(
    [0] => feff
    [1] => 56
    [2] => 6f
    [3] => 7a
    [4] => 61
    [5] => 63
)
`code`

This is what i get, what does it mean?

Comment: `feff` at the start of $firstKey is the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You could try trimming the key - `trim($firstKey, "\\xef\\xbb\\xbf")`. Or you could remove it from the file before you start importing it.

Comment: @nnichols i get same result. But it's multidimensional array, and for each one that represents a row in a csv file i get same result. For every array i have this error.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Your code for reading in the file is not included in your question so not sure what to suggest. What does `print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split(trim($firstKey, "\\xef\\xbb\\xbf")))));` output?

Comment: That's exactly what i did and i get same result. Then i did just  ` print_r(mb_str_split($driver['Vozac']));
       print_r(mb_str_split($firstKey1)); `  and i got `Array
(
    [0] => V
    [1] => o
    [2] => z
    [3] => a
    [4] => c
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => V
    [2] => o
    [3] => z
    [4] => a
    [5] => c
) `

I think it's not a correct one but i fixed it with:

`
$driver['Vozac'] = $driver[array_key_first($driver)]; `

Comment: Have a look at this - https://3v4l.org/LLJJ9#v and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184933/remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-imported-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an encoding issue. `string(8) "Vozac"` when `string(5) "Vozac"` expected?

```
var_dump(
    array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split('Vozac'))),
    array_map('dechex', array_map('mb_ord', mb_str_split($firstKey)))
)
```

As per your comment, the additional invisible character at the beginning of $firstKey is the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and because you `array_combine($header_row, $row)` foreach $row you are seeing this issue throughout the `$boltReportTrimed` array.

If you change the initial code which is opening the file and reading the lines of the csv then you won't have strange little hacks throughout your code.

```
function importCSV(string $file, bool $firstRowHeaders = false) {

    if (($fp = fopen($file, 'r')) !== false) {

        // Skip BOM if present, otherwise rewind to start of file
        if (fgets($fp, 4) !== "\xef\xbb\xbf") {
            rewind($fp);
        }

        // Read CSV into an array.
        $lines = array();
        $rows = 0;

        while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== false) {
            if ($firstRowHeaders === true && $rows === 0) {
                $lines['headers'] = $line;
            } else {
                $lines['rows'][] = $line;
            }
            $rows++;
        }

        fclose($fp);

        return $lines;
    }
}
```